# How to crop the difference of two images?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'd like to take these 2 images:

[image: frame 1]

[image: frame 2]

And essentially produce this:

[image: result]

I've gotten as far as using `compare` with `fuzz` to define the part that has changed. Is it possible to then get the bounding box of this area and crop the second frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something along these lines:

```
convert a.jpg b.jpg -colorspace gray -blur 0x2 \
       -compose difference -composite          \
       -threshold 20% out.jpg
```

Convert to greyscale and blur a little to hide small differences, then calculate the difference and threshold to make a binarised image like this:

[image]

Then I would go for a *Connected Components Analysis* to find the biggest object in the image, like this:

```
convert a.jpg b.jpg -colorspace gray -blur 0x2     \
   -compose difference -composite -threshold 20%   \
   -define connected-components:verbose=true       \
   -define connected-components:area-threshold=100 \
   -connected-components 8 out.jpg

Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 1029x1079+0+0 515.0,538.4 1102870 srgb(0,0,0)
  17: 76x147+326+564 366.5,641.4 5827 srgb(252,252,252)
  22: 18x50+358+612 365.1,635.3 568 srgb(0,0,0)
  11: 34x31+810+345 825.5,361.1 317 srgb(255,255,255)
  16: 57x97+25+539 52.3,587.2 286 srgb(255,255,255)
  14: 46x65+120+414 144.0,444.3 203 srgb(255,255,255)
  18: 27x49+23+579 36.9,601.0 118 srgb(255,255,255)
  24: 16x8+703+641 710.6,644.5 102 srgb(255,255,255)
```

The `-define connected-components:verbose=true` causes the individual blobs to be output as text for parsing.

The `-define connected-components:area-threshold=100` says to only output blobs larger than 100 pixels in area.

The `-connected-components 8` says to allow pixels that are 8-connected to be considered as belonging to the same object. 8-connected means North-East, South-East, South-West and North-East neighbours in addition to the normal North, East, South and West. By default, `ImageMagick` only considers 4-connected pixels as belonging to the same object - it's faster ;-)

And your player is item `id 17` - the second row and you can see the bounding box, and cut that out of the orignal with

```
convert b.jpg -crop 76x147+326+564 player.jpg
```

[image]

**Note:** You will need ImageMagick 6.8.9-10 or better for Connected Components Analysis.

Comment: Pleasure! You may need to diddle with the numbers and technique a little to optimise it for the rest of your images (which I can't see) but it should get you started.

Comment: **+ 2** Excellent answer!  :-)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know ImageMagick could do everything OpenCV could ;)