# Quantifying differences in an image sequence to measure activity

Tags: image-processing

I'm looking for a program that will enable me to quantity the difference between images in an image sequence over time.

We are hoping to use timelapse images to measure the activity of tadpoles by comparing how the images change over time. Tracking the movement of individuals isn’t necessary. The tadpoles are dark and the background of the aquarium is light, however the background isn’t uniform and some of the decor items like dark rocks and foliage make it so that all the tadpoles aren’t visible at all times.

Basically need a program that will allow me to quantity the differences/motion detected in an image sequence (i.e 209 images) and produce data that can be exported...

Any and all suggestions appreciated!!

Comment: What sort of data are you hoping it will produce? Over what period of time do you accumulate 209 images - 10 seconds, 10 minutes, 10 hours? Are you planning to share any images? What languages/tools do you work with?

Comment: Not sure of what data I'd like it to produce- something that will quantify how much the images change from frame to frame? Then have a dataframe that we can compare across replicates.... 209 images were time lapse photos taken ever 30 seconds- we may increase or decrease that though. I'm fairly new to programming- I've messed around with R, and ImageJ, but am open to using anything as long as there is a protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather vague and you don't supply any images or real indication of what you expect as results, so my answer will not be as thorough as it might otherwise be.

You don't mention any tools you are familiar with, but my recommendation would be Python and **OpenCV**. Alternatives are probably **scikit-image**, Python **Wand**.

In general, when trying to detect movement across a series of images, you would:

- try and work out what the background is
- look for movement by sutracting, or differencing, frames from the background
- clean up the difference image
- identify objects - maybe by shape or size or colour
- maybe track objects
- produce statistics

As regards working out the background, I did an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53665338/2836621) by finding the median pixel across all images at each location in the images. There is also an **OpenCV** tutorial [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html).

As regards cleaning up images, you can probably remove noise in the background subtraction with a small median filter, say 3x3 or 5x5 depending on the resolution of your images.

As regards detecting tadpoles, you will probably want to use **OpenCV** `findContours()` and filter by size, or colour, or circularity. There are some fairly decent tutorials on [PyImageSearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/). There is also an **ImageMagick** *"Connected Component"* analysis to find a tennis player that I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28043975/2836621).

Comment: Sorry for my vague request. Thank you for the suggestions... this is exactly what I was looking for.